# Transport Google Apps Script Project created for one sheet to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a mail merge program for one Google sheet.  I clicked **Tools** and **Script editor** and the created a project that included a `.gs` and `.html` files.

I have another Google sheet with the same structure but different emails and data.  I want to transport the Google Apps Script project from the previous worksheet to the new worksheet.  However, I'm not sure how to do this.

I tried looking to see if someone asked this question before but I couldn't find anything.  I'm also not sure if I misunderstanding how Google Apps Scripts are supposed to work.

I've posted the code below

```
function sendEmail() {

  var first = 1;
  var email = 3;
  var link = 6; 

  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('email_template');
  
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  var data = ws.getRange("A2:I" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  data.forEach(function(row){
        
      emailTemp.first = row[first]; 
      emailTemp.link = row[link]; 
      
      var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent(); 

      GmailApp.sendEmail(
          row[email], 
          "Email Subject ", 
          "Your email doesn't support HTML.", 
          {name: "Organization", htmlBody: htmlMessage, replyTo:"email@gmail.com"
          }  )
          
  });
  
}
```

Comment: Projects have access to all sheets. Please post you code

Comment: Can you please provide more details on why you want to do this? As Cooper said, you can access any spreadsheet from any script. Also, why not just copying and pasting the code to the new project? Arguably less work than coding a function for this.

Comment: Hi, I've added code.  I guess I need to use a different function besides getActiveSpreadSheet() in order to use a different Google Sheet?   I do think it would be convenient to just copy and paste code into new project that is associated with another sheet as lamblichus suggested.  My original thought was that there may be a way to simply copy the entire project including the HTML template into another project associated with a different spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

"A library is a script project whose functions can be reused in other scripts"

This is from:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries

First, make a library.
Write some functions in an app script project.
Click on deploy => New Deployment
For the type of deployment choose 'Library'
Copy the deployment URL

Next use your Library in a different Project:
In your target project click on the plus symbol next to the where it says Libraries
You have to input the library ID
The ID is in the url you copied before:
https://script.google.com/macros/library/d//1
Click Look up to find the library. You can rename it if you want.

To use the library:
Type the name of the library followed by a dot then the function just like any other service. Autocomplete should offer prompts.

Answer (score 0):

Appending files with different names from one project to another:

Gs:

```
function appendSelectedFilesDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('appendSelected1'), 'Append Selected Files');
}

function appendSelectedFilesIntoAnotherProject(obj) {
  const srcProjectId = obj.srcProjectId;
  const dstProjectId = obj.dstProjectId;
  const srcFileNames = obj.srcFileNames;
  var all = true;
  var fA = [];
  if (srcFileNames.length > 0) {
    all = false;
    fA = String(srcFileNames).split(',').map(n => n.trim());
  }
  if (srcProjectId && dstProjectId) {
    const base1 = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"
    const url1 = base1 + srcProjectId + "/content";
    const url2 = base1 + dstProjectId + "/content";
    const options1 = { "method": "get", "muteHttpExceptions": true, "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
    const res1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, options1);
    const data1 = JSON.parse(res1.getContentText());
    const srcfiles = data1.files;
    const options2 = { "method": "get", "muteHttpExceptions": true, "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
    const res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, options2);
    const data2 = JSON.parse(res2.getContentText());
    const dstFiles = data2.files;
    srcfiles.forEach(file => {
      if (file.source && file.name) {
        if (!all) {
          if (fA.indexOf(file.name) > -1) {
            dstFiles.push(file);
          }
        } else {
          dstFiles.push(file);
        }
      }
    });
    const request = { "files": dstFiles };
    const base = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"
    const url = base + dstProjectId + "/content"
    const options = { "method": "put", "request": request, "muteHttpExceptions": true, "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }, "contentType": "application/json", "payload": JSON.stringify(request) };
    const resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    console.log(resp);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<textarea rols="12" cols="60">' + resp + '</textarea>'), "Update Script Project");
  }
  return { "message": "Process Complete" };//minimally to remove the dialog
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>input{margin:2px 5px 2px 0;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="src" name="srcProjectId" size="60" placeholder="Enter Source Project Id" />
      <br /><input type="text" id="dst" name="dstProjectId" size="60" placeholder="Enter Destination Project Id" />
      <br /><input type="text" id="names" name="srcFileNames" size="60" placeholder ="Enter Desired Files separated by commas or nothing if you want all files." />
      <br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="process(this.parentNode);" />
    </form>
    <script>
      function process(obj) {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(obj){google.script.host.close();})
        .appendSelectedFilesIntoAnotherProject(obj);
        console.log('Form:',JSON.stringify(obj));
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If the new project has a file with the same name then this function will fail.  You can fix that yourself if you wish.  I just change the and move on.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use openById / openByUrl:

If you want to work with a spreadsheet that is different from the one to which the script is bound, just replace [getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet) with either [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) or [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl), where:

- `url` is the target spreadsheet URL.
- `id` is a specific part of the URL: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{THIS_IS_THE_ID}/edit#gid=0](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%7BTHIS_IS_THE_ID%7D/edit#gid=0)

So I'd suggest you to replace this:

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
```

With this:

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID").getSheetByName('Sheet1');
```

Or this:

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("SPREADSHEET_URL").getSheetByName('Sheet1');
```

#### Use Apps Script API / copy the content manually:

Also, you could use Apps Script API to [get the content](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent) from the source script and [update the target script with it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent), but I really doubt it is worth doing in your situation, as long as you don't have to copy a big amount of scripts.

Copying the script content manually will be arguably less work.